# Is xperia Ultra charger dock compatible with xperia Z?

Tags: sony-xperia, sony-xperia-z1

There's a low cost generic charger for Ultra but not for Z1. Is xperia Ultra charger dock compatible with xperia Z1?

http://dx.com/p/portable-cell-phone-usb-charging-dock-station-for-sony-xperia-z-ultra-xl39h-black-262275

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the charging dock for both Z Ultra and Z1.

Comment: Thanks, good to know there's at least some compatibility between accessories with Sony products... Any idea if a tablet could be charged with the same charger and vice versa?